# Name a variable after the content of a variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a variable and name it after the content of another variable.
For example

```
$newname = "x";
//dosomething to create the variable $x
```

Comment: Use arrays. Variable variables are evil maintenance nightmares.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called [variable-variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
${$newname} = 'stuff';
```

If you have more, consider using an array and [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) variables from it:

```
$vars = array(...);     // keys = variable name, value = variable value
extract($vars, EXTR_SKIP);
```

Comment: You just have to laugh, if you didn't, you'd cry.

Answer (score 1):

Check this :

```
$a = 'hello';
$$a = 'world';
echo "$a ${$a}";
echo "$a $world";
```

Hope to be useful.